# Unable to query using session.execute for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, session, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask sqlalchemy. However, when debug in command line, I found that `session.execute` return error.

```
Stock ='SHELL'
>>> db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM KJ WHERE Stock LIKE %s",(Stock,))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
        return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 978, in execute
        clause, params or {})
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 720, in execute
        return meth(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 317, in _execute_on_connection
        return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 793, in _execute_clauseelement
        keys = distilled_params[0].keys()
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

If I am using db.engine.execute, it works correctly with no error

```
db.engine.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE %s",(Stock,))
```

Also, if I import mysqldb, using cursors execute, it works fine too.

```
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KJ WHERE Stock LIKE %s",(Stock,))
```

the problem I suspect is the %s is not match with Stock for `session.execute`. I look through the sqlalchemy document but not understand.

> execute(clause, params=None, mapper=None, bind=None, **kw)¶
>   http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html

Comment: Have you tried taking out the extra comma in your select? `WHERE Stock LIKE %s",(Stock,))` ->  `WHERE Stock LIKE %s",(Stock))`

Comment: yes, not working with the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

The format for using SELECT for `execute` is the following:

`execute(clause, params=None, mapper=None, bind=None, **kw)`

There's an example solution in the docs using the following select:

```
result = session.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=:param",
        {"param":5}
    )
```

If your database connection is otherwise set up properly, following the docs, the following should work:

```
Stock ='SHELL'
db.engine.execute(text("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE :param"),{"param":Stock})
```

The idea is that you give the query to `text()` function which is valid parameter for `execute()`. That way you can execute any arbitrary SQL not natively available as an SQLalchemy function. I.e. the clause parameter takes in an executable statement (SQLalchemy function or other executable function, arbritrary string must be passed with `text()` and parameters are given as dictionaries.

Comment: W, Thanks. How about if `Stock =['SHELL',EXXON']` and `placeholders = ','.join([':param'] * len(Stock))`, how can I put multiple placeholders in `db.session.execute`?

Comment: Actually `db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE :param"),{"param":Stock})` works

Comment: So my answer did solve your problem? Or was there still something unclear?

Comment: It solve for the problems if one stock. Just if Stock is a list more than one, I need to put placeholders. `db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stockbalance IN :placeholders"),{placeholders:Stock})` return invalid syntax

Comment: Well yes, because you are using `LIKE`. If you want to search for multiple objects you either need to use `IN :param` or alternatively `LIKE :param OR LIKE :param2`. That said, I believe my answer did cover your original question.